# Are there any application/frameworks/gems/plugins for making a Webshop in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins, webshop

I need to make a very basic international webshop(2 different kind of products) Paying online, basket etc etc.

I am wondering if there are any gems/plugins to help me to make a webshop very very quickly and enough options to modify things in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at **Substruct** and **Spree**:

http://code.google.com/p/substruct/

http://spreecommerce.com/

Comment: Do you have any experience with some of these gems?

Comment: I tried substruct in the initial phase. But I think that spree is more updated and the community is more active! So I'd choose Spree. Even from the github page you can see a lot of updates and is built with rails 3: https://github.com/spree/spree

Answer (score 1):

[Webshop gems](https://www.ohloh.net/tags/cart/rails/webshop)   describes all of the projects that are tagged with webshop.

Some of the links for Spree are:
[A Rails 2 web shop with Spree](http://paulbuining.nl/?p=10)
[Spree](http://spreecommerce.com/)

Comment: Thanks. Spree looks indeed the best option. And most up to date.